# Typing in Woocommerce checkout form causes browser to report SSL issues

Tags: wordpress, security, google-chrome, ssl, woocommerce

I am working on a woocommerce website. The ssl seems to be working correctly until I start typing a few fields into the checkout. At that point the chrome lock icon changes to yellow for some reason. What things might be caused this? Everything on the page is secure ... images/fonts etc.

**EDIT:** It occurred to me right away after I asked this to check the chrome resources panel and sure enough I found the culprit, but I still don't really know how to tackle this at this point.

http://goods.ie/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/icons/valid.png

Comment: This would be much easier to debug if the assets weren't minified. There's obviously some kind of `keyup` JavaScript function firing which validates the input. The assets that it's trying to load aren't default WooCommerce assets...so the validation must be something custom. Again, hard to debug with minified JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines in your `woocommerce.css` file:

```
background-image:url(../../plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/icons/valid.png);

background-image:url(../../plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/icons/invalid.png);
```

are giving you the problem because they seems to be processed as:

```
http://goods.ie/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/icons/valid.png

http://goods.ie/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/icons/invalid.png
```

even though the stylesheet is called with the `https` protocol:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' 
      id='woocommerce_responsive_frontend_styles-css'       
      href='https://goods.ie/wp-content/themes/goods/woocommerce.css?ver=4.1.1' 
      type='text/css' 
      media='all' />
```

The reason seems to be that these image files currently **don't exists** and we get a 302 redirect to the `http` version with a 404 response.

So just make sure these files exists. Use the correct path and note that these files don't ship with WooCommerce.

Also consider upgrading to the latest WooCommerce version.

Comment: I think this one is the perfect answer for this problem. I spent last 20 minutes searching for solution and after I returned to this page then I found out this is already written :P my bad, I should start reading the solutions first. :P